# Authentication error in OAuth Sample Google Toolbox app

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, oauth, toolbox

I've ran into a problem and I don't know how to fix it. I've searched around to see if other people are having this issue but I can't find anything relative to my error. I'm using the OAuthSample example app. The google login works great but not the twitter login. The error that I'm getting is

```
Authentication error: Error Domain=com.google.HTTPStatus Code=401 "The operation couldn’t     be completed. (com.google.HTTPStatus error 401.)"
```

I've filled in myConsumerKey and myConsumerSecret correctly so I don't understand what the deal is. The modal drop down window will not even drop down and load the url page so I can put the twitter username and password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out. You have to put a callback url in the twitter settings or the authentication will fail.